# Doubt about external division of a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems

We all know that we can divide a line both internally and externally in some ratio. I can relate the concept of internal division of a line to the real world but does the concept of external division of a line have a physical meaning in the real world and if so what is it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Lines don't exist in the physical world.

Comment: I don't think i asked about lines. I asked about how the concept of external division of a line could be used in a real world application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use external division in physics. Suppose you have forces that depend on the distance, one attractive and one repulsive (say you have an electric field generated by a positive and a negative electric charges, of different magnitude, some distance $R$ apart). Then the equilibrium position is given by the external division. The ratio is equal to the square root of the magnitude of the charges.